# Tactic automation: simple decision procedure

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to automate a decision procedure for whether an ASCII character is whitespace or not. Here is what I currently have.

```
Require Import Ascii String.

Scheme Equality for ascii.

Definition IsWhitespace (c : ascii) := (c = "009"%char) \/ (c = "032"%char).

Definition isWhitespace (c : ascii) : {IsWhitespace c} + {not (IsWhitespace c)}.
Proof.
  unfold IsWhitespace.
  pose proof (ascii_eq_dec c "009"%char) as [H1|H1];
  pose proof (ascii_eq_dec c "032"%char) as [H2|H2];
  auto.
  right. intros [H3|H3]; auto.
Admitted.
```

What would be a good approach for making the proof more concise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frequently, making a proof more automated involves writing a bit more code than you started with, so that you can handle more cases.  Taking this approach, I adapted some boilerplate from [fiat-crypto](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat-crypto/blob/5da42750e1349ce761107902ef3039195adac62c/src/Util/Decidable.v):

```
Require Import Coq.Strings.Ascii Coq.Strings.String.

Class Decidable (P : Prop) := dec : {P} + {~P}.
Arguments dec _ {_}.
Notation DecidableRel R := (forall x y, Decidable (R x y)).

Global Instance dec_or {A B} {HA : Decidable A} {HB : Decidable B} : Decidable (A \/ B).
Proof. hnf in *; tauto. Defined.
Global Instance dec_eq_ascii : DecidableRel (@eq ascii) := ascii_dec.
```

With this boilerplate, your proof becomes

```
Definition IsWhitespace (c : ascii) := (c = "009"%char) \/ (c = "032"%char).
Definition isWhitespace (c : ascii) : Decidable (IsWhitespace c) := _.
```

which is about as short as a proof can be.  (Note that `:= _` is the same as `. Proof. exact _. Defined.`, which itself is the same as `. Proof. typeclasses eauto. Defined.`.)

Note that this is fairly similar to ejgallego's proof, since `tauto` is the same as `intuition fail`.

Note also that [the original boilerplate in fiat-crypto](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat-crypto/blob/5da42750e1349ce761107902ef3039195adac62c/src/Util/Decidable.v) is much longer, but also more powerful than simply using `hnf in *; tauto`, and handles a few dozen different sorts of decidable propositions.

Comment: This is super interesting! Would you mind explaining the `Arguments` aspect? And why use `Notation` instead of `Definition`?

Comment: Also... This approach looks a lot like the `Coq.Structures.Equalities` part of the standard library, is there any particular reason not to use it?

Comment: The `Arguments` bit lets you write `dec (x = y)` to mean "find an instance of decidability of `x = y` by typeclass resolution and use that here".  Without it, `dec (x = y)` is a type error, because `dec` means "find the first instance of decidability of any proposition, by typeclass resolution, and use that here".

Answer (score 4):

The proof is almost the most concise it can be! At most what you can do is to call a more powerful tactic such as `intuition`:

```
Definition isWhitespace (c : ascii) : {IsWhitespace c} + {not (IsWhitespace c)}.
Proof.
now unfold IsWhitespace;
    case (ascii_eq_dec c "009"%char);
    case (ascii_eq_dec c " "%char); intuition.
```

Comment: Just a bit more concise reformulation of the above: `compute; case (ascii_eq_dec c "009"%char), (ascii_eq_dec c " "%char); tauto.` We use `compute` to unfold everything here.

Answer (score 4):

Following the spirit of Jason's answer, we can of course use some libraries dealing with decidable equality to arrive at your result:

This will declare `ascii` as a type with decidable equality:

```
From Coq Require Import Ascii String ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
From mathcomp Require Import eqtype ssrnat.

Lemma ascii_NK : cancel N_of_ascii ascii_of_N.
Proof. exact: ascii_N_embedding. Qed.

Definition ascii_eqMixin := CanEqMixin ascii_NK.
Canonical ascii_eqType := EqType _ ascii_eqMixin.
```

In this style, usually you state your properties are decidable propositions so there is nothing to prove:

```
Definition IsWhitespaceb (c : ascii) := [|| c == "009"%char | c == " "%char].
```

However if you want, you can of course recover the non-computational one:

```
Definition IsWhitespace (c : ascii) := (c = "009"%char) \/ (c = "032"%char).

Lemma whitespaceP c : reflect (IsWhitespace c) (IsWhitespaceb c).
Proof. exact: pred2P. Qed.
```

Some more automation can be used of course.